# IDX10501: Signature validation failed. Unable to match key

Tags: oauth-2.0, jwt, azure-active-directory, openid-connect, adfs

I have a task to authenticate the APIs using ADFS Token which is from an external application, so I have created two applications one is MVC application lets say **A**  which authenticates using with SSO credentials and another one is WEB API application lets say **B**, So here FROM A, I am calling B's API using A's ADFS Token but, I am getting error. Does anyone help me how to resolve this?

Below is code in WEB API  in application **B**

```
           ConfigurationManager<OpenIdConnectConfiguration> configManager =
                new ConfigurationManager<OpenIdConnectConfiguration>(openIdConfig, new 
                                                                     OpenIdConnectConfigurationRetriever());

            OpenIdConnectConfiguration config = 
            configManager.GetConfigurationAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
            result.EmailId = Claims.FirstOrDefault(claim => claim.Type == "upn").Value;
            result.WindowsNTId = Claims.FirstOrDefault(claim => claim.Type == "unique_name").Value;
            var utc0 = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc);
            result.TokenCreatedOn = utc0.AddSeconds(Convert.ToInt64((Claims.FirstOrDefault(claim => 
            claim.Type == "iat").Value)));
            result.TokenExpiresOn = utc0.AddSeconds(Convert.ToInt64((Claims.FirstOrDefault(claim => 
            claim.Type == "exp").Value)));

            // Use System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt library to validate the token
            JwtSecurityTokenHandler tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();

            var tokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
            {
                ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                ValidateIssuer = true,
                ValidIssuer = config.Issuer,
                IssuerSigningKeys = config.SigningKeys,
                ValidateAudience = true,
                ValidAudience = expectedAudience
            };

            SecurityToken validatedToken;

            try
            {
                var claimsPrincipal = tokenHandler.ValidateToken(RawData, tokenValidationParameters, 
                out validatedToken);

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

            }
```

**Below is the Exception Message.**

```
    IDX10501: Signature validation failed. Unable to match key: 
    kid: 'System.String'.
    Exceptions caught:System.Text.StringBuilder'. 
    token: 'System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt.JwtSecurityToken'.
```

Answer (score 4):

It happens when the decoded key (kid) is not a valid one (perhaps it is an old one, as the certificate keys usually change).

From https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-identitymodel-extensions-for-dotnet/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.IdentityModel.JsonWebTokens/JsonWebTokenHandler.cs

```
if (kidExists)
{
     if (kidMatched)
     throw LogHelper.LogExceptionMessage(new SecurityTokenInvalidSignatureException(LogHelper.FormatInvariant(TokenLogMessages.IDX10511, keysAttempted, jwtToken.Kid, exceptionStrings, jwtToken)));

     throw LogHelper.LogExceptionMessage(new SecurityTokenSignatureKeyNotFoundException(LogHelper.FormatInvariant(TokenLogMessages.IDX10501, jwtToken.Kid, exceptionStrings, jwtToken)));
}
```

In my case, the cause of the issue was the null first byte present in the key modulus. The solution was to remove the first null byte.

https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-identitymodel-extensions-for-dotnet/issues/1122

```
var configManager = new ConfigurationManager<OpenIdConnectConfiguration>(configFileUrl, new OpenIdConnectConfigurationRetriever());
var openIdConfig = configManager.GetConfigurationAsync().Result; #region workaround for "Error validating identity token : IDX10511"
//The issue you are facing is caused by the null first byte.
//This is contrary to the JWA (https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7518#section-6.3.1.1).
//.NET Core will account for the null byte and .NET framework, apparently, won't.
List<SecurityKey> keys = new List<SecurityKey>();
foreach (var key in openIdConfig.SigningKeys)
{
     if (key.CryptoProviderFactory.IsSupportedAlgorithm("SHA256"))
     {
          var modulus = ((RsaSecurityKey)key).Parameters.Modulus;
          var exponent = ((RsaSecurityKey)key).Parameters.Exponent;

          if (modulus.Length == 257 && modulus[0] == 0)
          {
               var newModulus = new byte[256];
               Array.Copy(modulus, 1, newModulus, 0, 256);
               modulus = newModulus;
          }
          RSAParameters rsaParams = new RSAParameters();
          rsaParams.Modulus = modulus;
          rsaParams.Exponent = exponent;

          keys.Add(new RsaSecurityKey(rsaParams));
     }
     else
     {
          keys.Add(key);
     }
}
#endregion

TokenValidationParameters validationParameters =
new TokenValidationParameters
{
     // Validate the JWT Issuer (iss) claim
     ValidateIssuer = true,
     ValidIssuer = issuer,

     //// Validate the JWT Audience (aud) claim
     ValidateAudience = true,
     ValidAudience = audience,

     ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
     IssuerSigningKeys = keys,

     RequireExpirationTime = true,
     ValidateLifetime = true,
     RequireSignedTokens = true,
};

// Now validate the token. If the token is not valid for any reason, an exception will be thrown by the method
SecurityToken validatedToken;
JwtSecurityTokenHandler handler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();

var claimsPrincipal = handler.ValidateToken(idToken, validationParameters, out validatedToken);
```

Comment: I edited my answer, I guess it wasn't complete, could you remove the downvotes ?